# What am I doing wrong to calculate V from numpy array? I can not get array with "V" values

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = 3.9 #m
L = 7.8 #m

x = np.arange(0,L+0.1,0.1)

def fun_v():
    for value in x:
        if 0 < x < a :
            V= P*(1-(a/L))
        if a < x < L :
            V= -P*(a/L)
    return (V) 
V = fun_v()

print('V =',V)
```

#ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: You are not returning anything

Comment: this whole function doesn't make any sense... can you please explain your question?

Comment: You are comparing `x` in the for loop. Maybe you meant `0 < value < a` and `a < value < L`

Comment: you can't use an array in a `0<x<a` expression or in an `if`.  Those only work for single values, not multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues are the following:

- You are **comparing an array instead of a value** in a condition, which is ambiguous.
  Try `0 < value < a` instead `0 < x < a`

  To give an example of what you are doing:

  1. You are first assigning the `x` like `[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ... ]`
  2. Then you are comparing `0 < [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ... ] < 3.9` at line `0 < x < a`
- Also, the variable `P` **is not defined**. You will need to provide a value of `P` like the ones you provide for `a` and `L`.
- To get an array of `V` values, you will need to push the calculated `V` values in an empty array or you can use the [`map` function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/).

A working example:

```
import numpy as np
a = 3.9 
L = 7.8 
P = 10 # P is defined

x = np.arange(0,L+0.1,0.1)

def fun_v():
    arr = [] # empty array is initialized
    for value in x:
        if 0 < value < a : # value is compared instead of x
            V = P*(1-(a/L))
            arr.append(V) # V is pushed after calculation
        if a < value < L :
            V = -P*(a/L)
            arr.append(V)
    return arr # return the array of v values
V = fun_v()

print(V)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `fancy indexing` technique of `NumPy`, which will be both quicker and easier to comprehend:

```
import numpy as np
a = 3.9 #m
L = 7.8 #m
P=1
x = np.arange(0,L+0.1,0.1)
x[(0<x)&(x>a)]=P*(1-(a/L))
x[(a<x)&(x>L)]=-P*(a/L)
x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the comparison is wrong and you didn't declare what is p. I am actually not sure what you trying to do at the end as it wont return anything. but from your code, I believe it suppose to be like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = 3.9 #m
L = 7.8 #m
x = np.arange(0,L+0.1,0.1)

def fun_v(x_):
    for value in x_:
        P = 1 # declare your P value
        if 0 < value < a:
            V = P*(1-(a/L))
        elif a < value < L:
            V = -P*(a/L)
    return V

V = fun_v(x)
print(V)
```

But in this code, the V value will not be an array or list. it will just return a value. if you would like to calculate all the x  value and separate it in different list or array, you might need an append.